# IllegalThreadStateException in webbrowser (windows)

Tags: java, applet

I'm getting an IllegalThreadStateException.

All is ok under Eclipse's debugger but when I'm trying to test it on Firefox it starts to fail. First run is OK, after refreshing webpage im getting that exception.

here is the code:

```
public void init() {
    try {           
        SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() 
        {
            public void run() 
            {                   
                createGUI();
                createConnection();
            }
        });
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    { 
        System.err.println("createGUI didn't complete successfully");
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.err.println(e.toString());
    }
}


private void createConnection()
{       
    _connectionThread = ConnectionThread.getInstance();
    _connectionThread.setServer(getCodeBase().getHost());
    _connectionThread.start(); <------ Exception        
}
```

Im new in Java, tbh it's my first applet. I know that I'm doing something wrong, but I cannot find what it is.

edit: from console

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(Unknown Source)
at com.onlinegame.gameclient.GameClient.init(GameClient.java:76)
at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.AWTAppletAdapter.init(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException
    at java.lang.Thread.start(Unknown Source)
    at com.onlinegame.gameclient.GameClient.createConnection(GameClient.java:175)
    at com.onlinegame.gameclient.GameClient.access$100(GameClient.java:34)
    at com.onlinegame.gameclient.GameClient$1.run(GameClient.java:81)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

Comment: Could you provide the full stack trace?

Comment: IllegalThreadStateException is throw when you try to invoke a thread when the request is already commited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 _connectionThread = ConnectionThread.getInstance();
```

looks like ConnectionThread is a Singleton (is that true?) and extends Thread. If that is correct you may have a problem as a Thread can only be started once ([Thread.start()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start%28%29)). If you attempt to start the same Thread instance a second time, it will fail with a `java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException`.

To solve this, create a new Thread object on every request or cache the result of execution in the singletion. How to exactly implement that depends on what you want to achieve with the thread and the design of your app.

Comment: Ok, I understand but this problem occurs when the applat starts. after refreshing the webpage applet starts again with exception.
Is that possible that after refreshing an webpage under firefox existing and running applet is initialized again?

Comment: You said in your question that it works once and then fails on refreshing the webpage. I don't have a firm grasp of the applet lifecycle, but if the singleton remains the same through the refresh (what I suspect) you would access the same (already started) ConnectionThread instance after a refresh. That would explain why all attempts, except the first, to start it fail with the given exception.

Comment: ok, I understand and now I know what to do with this exception. Thank you.
But the next problem is 'how to' catch an situation, when the webpage is begin to refresh. I need to stop and exit all the threads and clear singletons.

Comment: Ok I see the problem. Your init() method should only be executed once (if it is the applets init() method). I honestly don't know if Firefox does weird things but I would suspect otherwise. Maybe check if there are other places where ConnectionThread.start() is called in your applet. Is your applet "alone" or are there other applets that may share ConnectionThread?

Comment: Resolving this problem depends on what you want/need to do. You could try to avoid using a Singleton or push the thread starting into the singleton and prevent starting it twice.

Comment: There are no other applets. Exception is thrown in createConnection, there is only one call of that function, inside init(). Looks like objects still exists after refreshing the page. Inside ConnectionThread there is an connection attempt, and it's not interrupted by webpage's refresh.

Comment: [This](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/firefox-java-applet-cache-551644/) may point to the root cause. Apparenlty firefox keeps the java classloader cached after creating a an applet for the first time. On refresh the applet is destroyed, then reinitialized but the singleton remains in the class cache and is loaded from there. A quick'n'dirty workaround may be (not tested!): Clear the singletons state in the applet's destroy() method (i.e. set instance to null ...). But that is bad and will hurt you in the long (and most likely short) run.

Comment: *comment length exceeded* A better aproach would be to get rid of the singleton (i.e. static variables) and to make sure that your applet is fully initialized on init() and properly cleaned up on destroy() without relying on static member variables that would remain in the class cache. Rethink your design - do you want to share the _ConnectionThread_ throughout your applet or do you want to share the _connection_ that is created by that thread?

Comment: Thank you for your help. Now I fully understand the problem.